# Could not find file 'SqlAccess.dll'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

When running

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyAssembly
FROM 'S:\SourceCode\TryUDF\bin\Debug\TryUDF.dll'
```

an error is returned:

```
Could not find file 'SqlAccess.dll' in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\'.
```

The assembly is a class library built with VS2008.  SQL Server is 2005.
SqlAcesss.dll exists in the above location, and that Binn directory is in the PATH environment variable for the system.
How can I diagnose what is causing this problem?

Comment: Someone replied suggesting restarting the server.  That has been tried and no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  Since I had followed procedures suggested by Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer to secure the SQL Server, possibly incompletely or incorrectly, the SQL Server service account did not have permissions as required to the folder where sqlaccess.dll exists.  Immediately upon granting permissions (read, execute, list), the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

If it was built with VS2008 check to see if the references to SQL objects in the project are using SQL 2008 libraries.  That could be your problem.  You might need to recompile your library against SQL 2005 libraries.

Comment: No SQL Server 200x references at all.  The data references are System.Data, System.Data.DataSetExtensions.  The other references are System, System.Core, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq (which I could probably remove the latter two).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the article right now but I'm pretty sure it's related to the DLL not being signed or the TRUSTWORTHY setting on the SQL Server.  The error says file not found but it actually means it wasn't able to load it (not the same thing!).

I'd suggest re-asking on stackoverflow.com if you don't get it sorted.